# Profile picture not showing in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a problem with the contacts web part and the organization tree. Photos of users in SharePoint Online are not displayed, and e.g. in the Teams application, photos from O365 synchronize correctly.

Has anyone had this problem and managed to find a solution?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint out of the box web parts or any custom SPFx or 3rd party web parts?

Comment: SharePoint out of the box web parts